# icmp limited in many network spaces?

Tags: linux, limit, namespace, icmp

I wrote small script do show example usage of ip netns on unused class size C (here changed into 192.168.10)

```
#!/bin/sh
network=192.168.10

for id in `seq 0 127`; do
 ip netns del test-$id;
done;

bring(){
 set -x
 idprev=$1
 id=$2
 ipprev=$(( $idprev * 2 ))
 ip=$(( $idprev * 2 + 1 ))
 ip netns add test-$id
 ip netns exec test-$id ip link set dev lo up 
 ip netns exec test-$id sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding=1
 ip netns exec test-$id sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.hop_limit=255
 ip link add test-$1-$2 type veth peer name test-$2-$1
 [ $idprev -eq 0 ] && ip link set test-$1-$2 up
 [ $idprev -eq 0 ] && ip a a ${network}.$ipprev/31 dev test-$1-$2
 [ $idprev -eq 0 ] && ip r a ${network}.0/24 via ${network}.$ip

 [ $idprev -gt 0 ] && ip link set test-$1-$2 netns test-$idprev up
 [ $idprev -gt 0 ] && ip netns exec test-$idprev ip a a ${network}.$ipprev/31 dev test-$1-$2
 [ $idprev -gt 0 ] && ip netns exec test-$idprev ip r a ${network}.0/24 via $network.$ip
 ip link set test-$2-$1 netns test-$id up
 ip netns exec test-$id ip a a ${network}.$ip/31 dev test-$2-$1
 ip netns exec test-$id ip r a default via ${network}.$ipprev
}

for id in `seq 0 127`; do
    bring $id $(( $id + 1 ))
done;
```

I run it, it created namespaces - so i try to test it. On small "range" - it works fine:

```
undefine@uml:~$ mtr -n -r -c1  192.168.10.10
Start: Sat Apr  4 00:16:25 2015
HOST: uml                         Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 192.168.50.253             0.0%     1    1.1   1.1   1.1   1.1   0.0
  2.|-- 192.168.51.9               0.0%     1    3.1   3.1   3.1   3.1   0.0
  3.|-- 192.168.52.32              0.0%     1    3.5   3.5   3.5   3.5   0.0
  4.|-- 192.168.10.1               0.0%     1    4.2   4.2   4.2   4.2   0.0
  5.|-- 192.168.10.3               0.0%     1    2.8   2.8   2.8   2.8   0.0
  6.|-- 192.168.10.5               0.0%     1    3.6   3.6   3.6   3.6   0.0
  7.|-- 192.168.10.7               0.0%     1   10.9  10.9  10.9  10.9   0.0
  8.|-- 192.168.10.10              0.0%     1    3.1   3.1   3.1   3.1   0.0
```

But - when i try to achieve later hops - i didn't receive icmp respons. It looks like some kind of icmp limit:

```
undefine@uml:~$ mtr -n -r -c10  192.168.10.100
Start: Sat Apr  4 00:19:09 2015
HOST: uml                         Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 192.168.50.253             0.0%    10    2.2   1.3   0.8   2.2   0.0
  2.|-- 192.168.51.9               0.0%    10    3.0   3.4   2.7   4.0   0.0
  3.|-- 192.168.52.32              0.0%    10    4.9   3.9   2.7   7.7   1.4
  4.|-- 192.168.10.1              90.0%    10    2.7   2.7   2.7   2.7   0.0
  5.|-- 192.168.10.3              90.0%    10    2.9   2.9   2.9   2.9   0.0
  6.|-- 192.168.10.5              90.0%    10    3.3   3.3   3.3   3.3   0.0
  7.|-- 192.168.10.7              90.0%    10    3.6   3.6   3.6   3.6   0.0
  8.|-- 192.168.10.9              90.0%    10    4.3   4.3   4.3   4.3   0.0
  9.|-- 192.168.10.11             80.0%    10    5.6   4.7   3.7   5.6   1.0
 10.|-- 192.168.10.13             50.0%    10    7.0   5.8   2.5  12.0   3.8
 11.|-- 192.168.10.15             80.0%    10    2.8   3.3   2.8   3.7   0.0
 12.|-- 192.168.10.17             90.0%    10    3.1   3.1   3.1   3.1   0.0
 13.|-- ???                       100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 14.|-- 192.168.10.21             90.0%    10    3.5   3.5   3.5   3.5   0.0
 15.|-- ???                       100.0    10    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

normal icmp pings - works fine to all hosts:

```
undefine@uml:~/filmy$ ping 192.168.10.100
PING 192.168.10.100 (192.168.10.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.10.100: icmp_seq=1 ttl=12 time=3.68 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.100: icmp_seq=2 ttl=12 time=5.73 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.10.100: icmp_seq=3 ttl=12 time=2.85 ms
^C
--- 192.168.10.100 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.851/4.090/5.733/1.211 ms
```

firewall is empty, conntrack is off, on dmesg there is nothing..
on every namespace i see icmp echo packets flow with decreased ttl. I tried to set net.ipv4.icmp_ratelimit to various values - from 0, 1 to big numbers. But it didn't help. I think that there is yet one limit for icmp replies from linux. But - where it can be?